# errors communicating with MT Scale over TCP/IP - Getting close

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient, networkstream

I am using VB.net 2015 to try to communicate with a scale.  I have somethings working where i can talk to scale a bit but i get random vb.net errors.  Also most of the time I send the command and i get and error back from the scale so i send it again and the scale responds correctly and then i get a second response of an error.

It feels like the message i am trying to send is not getting there in one piece so i have to send it twice.  Any help is great appreciated.  i have so many hours into trying to make it work i am going blind.

Still learning and this is my first project using TCPClient and NetworkStream

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class Form1
    'Private ClientWritter As TCPControlWritter
    'Public Client As TcpClient


    Private port As Int32 = 1701
    Private client As TcpClient
    Dim stream As Net.Sockets.NetworkStream


'opens connection

    Sub OpenConnection(ByVal server As [String])
        Try
            client = New TcpClient(server, port)
            client.ReceiveTimeout = 200
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub


'closes connection

    Sub CloseConnection()
        Try
            If stream IsNot Nothing Then
                stream.Close()
                stream = Nothing
            End If

            client.Close()
            client = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub


'takes the text from textbox and sends it to scale

    Sub SendMesssage(ByVal message As [String])
        Try

            Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message & vbCrLf)


            ' Get a client stream for reading and writing.

            If stream Is Nothing Then stream = client.GetStream()


            ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            If stream.CanWrite Then
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
                stream.Flush()
            End If


            Debug.WriteLine("Sent: " & message)

            ' Receive the TcpServer.response.
            ' Buffer to store the response bytes.
            data = New [Byte](256) {}

            ' String to store the response ASCII representation.
            Dim responseData As String = ""

            If stream.CanRead Then

                ' Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)

                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
                Debug.WriteLine(responseData)

            End If

        Catch e As ArgumentNullException
            Debug.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e)
        Catch e As SocketException
            Debug.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e)
        End Try

        txtMessage.Text = ""
        txtMessage.Focus()
 End Sub
```

---

'here is the data i get back from the scale.  The "sent" lines are my input.

```
53 Ready for user
>


Sent: user admin

83 Command not recognized
>

83 Command not recognized
>


Sent: user admin

12 Access OK
>

83 Command not recognized
>
```

Comment: what is the actual problem? what "random vb.net errors" do you get and on what line?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on the errors.  Right now i am less worried about the errors i get in VB because most of the time I am able to send a message and get a response. I can connect, communicate and disconnect most of the time without any VB errors. 

My problem is that if i use the program TeraTerm i can communicate smoothly with the scale.  When i use my vb.net program I get a lot of "83 Command not recognized" messages from the scale.  I think the way that i am sending the message via stream.write() is mixing up the data or sending it in partials.